# Monitor as synchronization on Windows

Tags: winapi, synchronization

Is there any implementation of [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) on Windows? I didn't see any win32 API references Monitor.

Answer (score 3):

Windows does not have a monitor implementation of its own.  However, Vista introduced [Condition Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052.aspx) and [Slim Reader/Writer locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937.aspx), which can be used together to create a monitor implementation.

Comment: Yes, condition variable or SRW lock are necessary construct to implement monitor, but I am wondering why such a fundamental concept is not implemented directly by the OS (Windows here).

Comment: You would have to ask Microsoft about that.

Comment: @Thomson: Because it isn't "fundamental", and certainly not a primitive.  The OS only provides services for other libraries and frameworks to build on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. Windows has monitors and monitor functions:
EnterCriticalSection is similar to POSIX pthread_mutex_lock (enters the monitor).
LeaveCriticalSection is similar to POSIX pthread_mutex_unlock (leaves monitor).

SleepConditionVariableCS similar to POSIX pthread_cond_wait.

WakeConditionVariable ... POSIX pthread_cond_signal.

WakeAllConditionVariable ... POSIX pthread_cond_broadcast

All these funcions you can find here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360(v=vs.85).aspx