# Can a thread be preempted while in the middle of a critical section?

Tags: .net, c, windows, multithreading, clr

Are critical section locks made possible by disabling interrupts in Windows? If that is the case, then a thread cannot be preempted while it is in the middle of a critical section.

But if that were the case, i.e. if a thread could not be preempted while executing a critical section, that that would make the whole point of *pulsing* a monitor somewhat less important than it would be if the thread could be asked to evacuate CPU even while it was in the middle of a critical section.

So, my real question(s) are:

1. How are monitors implemented in Windows?
2. Can a thread be preempted while it is in the middle of a critical section?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows is designed so that threads, even when running in kernel mode, [are always preemptible and always interruptible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540600(v=vs.85).aspx).  So critical sections are certainly not implemented by disabling interrupts and do not prevent preemption.

In fact, if a user-mode thread could block interrupts and/or preemption, it would be trivial for a user-mode process to inadvertently crash the entire system.  So no modern operating system behaves in the way you are suggesting.

In Windows, [monitors are usually implemented using condition variables,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836313/886887) which are provided as a primitive by the thread scheduler.  I believe this is also true of POSIX.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. Sure, what you're saying makes a lot of sense. What I was wrongly assuming was that *during the acquisition and release of the lock*, the procedure would step into kernel mode, just like it does when user code does a `CreateThread` or `ThreadFork` in any OS API. Although it runs the thread in user mode, it has to get to the *thread root* and copy stuff from the stack to the registers.

Comment: But understandably, even if it did get into the kernel to acquire and release the lock, it would still not rule out the possibility of a miscreant forgetting to release the lock or of an exception occurring during the execution of a critical section, thus potentially jeopardizing the safety of the entire system, as you point out.

Comment: I will read the documentation you have linked to, but could you please quickly satisfy my curiosity as to the following question? Is the acquisition of a lock in Windows run in user-mode?

Comment: I followed the second link in your answer and one of the links that that page has says: *"Condition variables are user-mode objects that cannot be shared across processes."* So I am guessing that that means that lock acquisition in Windows is a user-mode routine.

Comment: The API functions that are used with critical sections and condition variables start out in user mode, and *may* complete entirely in user mode.  Claiming a critical section, for example, won't enter kernel mode unless another thread already owns the critical section and doesn't release it before the spin lock expires.  If the lock is contended, though, the thread has to block in a way that allows other threads to run, and that requires kernel-mode APIs; specifically, it creates and/or uses an event object - see CreateEvent.  (I'm less familiar with CVs but they're broadly similar.)

Comment: Of course, if you use a cross-process locking mechanism instead, [such as a mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266(v=vs.85).aspx), the API calls always enter kernel mode.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx) critical section blocks do not disable interrupts.  The only difference between critical sections and mutexes is that critical sections are only valid within the context of the same process.  So they cannot be used to synchronize different processes.  Other threads can continue running,  and interrupts are not even disabled.  The other threads will be blocked only if they enter the same critical section when the first thread is still using it.

Also,  even with disabled interrupts the other threads can run on modern hardware,  because most of CPUs now are multiple cores.  It's really hard to find single core CPU these days.  With multiple cores multiple threads can run in parallel without pre-empting each other.

Comment: Thank you indeed. You make an interesting observation about interrupts being disabled in the face of multi-core CPU's.